# InvalidCastException when executing a select

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a query that looks like this:

```
 surveyCompleted = from s in surveyCompleted 
                where agentTickets.Contains(s.TicketID.Value) || s.UserID == new Guid(txtUserID.Text) select s;
```

The problem is that after this statement I can't do anything with surveyCompleted because I get an InvalidCastException. Any ideas why this happens? All the other select statement with surveyCompleted work just fine but this one fails? Could it be from the statement "agentTickets.Contains(s.TicketID.Value)" in the where clause?

Comment: *Where* do you get the exception? Please show how you're *using* `surveyCompleted`.

Comment: It crashes on surveyCompleted.ToList() or when I try to enumerate the collection in Visual studio debug mode I still get the exception

Comment: And are there any more details within the exception? Basically, please give us as much information as you can. (We don't currently even know whether this is LINQ to Objects or LINQ to SQL etc...)

Comment: LINQ to SQL, in a post bellow it mentions that the crash occurs because of the new Guid() which is delayed until the query is enumerated

Comment: Could you please post the actual text of the exception and the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `txtUserID` is a `TextBox` (name leads to think so), then `new Guid(txtUserID.Text)` would throw if it's not containing a precise `Guid`-like string (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

Answer (score 1):

try with this code

```
from s in surveyCompleted 
                where agentTickets.Contains(s.TicketID.Value) || s.UserID == new Guid(txtUserID.Text).ToString() select s;
```

Comment: I am pretty new to linq but I believe you are right, it should crash when I convert create the Guid but it is delayed and it crashes when I try to enumerate the query. That's the moment when the query and the method is actually executed

Answer (score 0):

This is a LINQ to SQL, correct?

Make sure that `s.TicketID` is never a NULL:

```
!Convert.IsDBNull(s.TicketID) && agentTickets.Contains(s.TicketID.Value)
```